# How can I use LINQ to Entities (with a transform) to return a nested dataset?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm performing a transform on the entity objects into my own models (CustomerModel and OrderModel).

I currently have an IQueryable method that returns my Customers:

```cs
IQueryable<CustomerModel> GetCustomers()
{
    return from c in entities.Customers
           select new CustomerModel {
               CustomerId = c.CustomerId,
               CustomerName = c.CustomerName
               // Orders = ??
           };
}
```

In my CustomerModel, you can see I have an array of Orders.

```cs
class CustomerModel {
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public OrderModel[] Orders { get; set; }
}

class OrderModel {
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how set Orders inside of the Customer object when the Orders type is Array.

I was able to do it when I changed the CustomerModel's Orders to be IEnumerable instead of an array and you cannot use .ToArray() with LINQ to Entities, so I'm stuck.

So my question is: is this possible to do using an Array for Orders?

**Answers to Questions:**

- Why an Array?  I'm returning an array (for consumption by other projects) elsewhere and it made sense to have the Orders be an Array as well.

**Also, you cannot use ToArray() for the Orders, this error is thrown:**

```
System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Proj.Models.Orders[] ToArray[Orders](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Proj.Models.Orders])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

Comment: Why do you want an array?  First off, you *can* use .ToArray() from an Enumerable or a Queryable, but an array implies things (like ordering and mutability) that make it very difficult for L2E to track.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `Orders` are accessible from `Customers`, you can try:

```
IQueryable<CustomerModel> GetCustomers()
{
    return from c in entities.Customers
           select new CustomerModel {
               CustomerId = c.CustomerId,
               CustomerName = c.CustomerName
               Orders = from o in c.Orders
                        select new Order{
                            OrderId = o.OrderId,
                            ...
                        }
           };
}
```

This requires you to change `Customer.Orders` to an `IEnumerable<Order>`. That is the only way to load the object graph in one request to the database.

Comment: I believe you may be right about this.  I had a feeling IEnumerable is the only way.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not very good practise when our Data Access method returns business objects (models). You can edit your queries for example in such way:

```
IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomers()
{
    return entities.Customers;
}

IQueryable<Order> GetOrders()
{
    return entities.Orders;
}

IEnumerable<CustomerModel> GetCustomerModels()
{
    var result = from c in GetCustomers()
                 let orderModels = from o in GetOrders() 
                                   where o.CustomerId == c.CustomerId
                                   select new OrderModel
                                   {....}
                 select new CustomerModel  
                 {
                     CustomerId = c.CustomerId,
                     CustomerName = c.CustomerName,
                     Orders = orderModels.ToArray()
                 }; 
    return result;
}
```

if this solution is not useful for you, please describe your "entities"

Comment: The IQueryable method is on a special Repository.  The Models being returned are also on the Repository level.  The reason is to keep private the actual ADO.NET Entities.  Another reason is so we can swap out the back without any code impact.

Comment: You cannot call ToArray() using LINQ to Entities!  This is the error that results: System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Proj.Models.Orders[] ToArray[Orders](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Proj.Models.Orders])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: In this case you must first perform enumeration of your entities.. not very good idea, but still.. can you describe your Customer entity in details?

Comment: The entities were made up for this example.  But they will be in their respective MS SQL tables, accessed using ADO.NET Entities and LINQ to SQL.  The Customer to Order relationship is a one to many.